# aggregate with categorical variable in r

Tags: r, aggregate

I need to aggregate by Date, my "Day" dataset:

>

```
head(Day)
        Date Day Month Year  TimeDay Room Temperature Light     RH
1 02/09/2013   2     9 2013 08:00:00    2        21.7 71.76 100.00
2 02/09/2013   2     9 2013 08:15:00    2        21.7 61.27 100.00
3 02/09/2013   2     9 2013 08:30:00    2        21.7 58.96 100.00
4 02/09/2013   2     9 2013 08:45:00    2        21.8 52.96 100.00
5 02/09/2013   2     9 2013 09:00:00    2        22.0 59.92  86.26
6 02/09/2013   2     9 2013 09:15:00    2        22.2 65.12  84.01
```

but including the column 6, which corresponds to Room number:

```
newDay <- aggregate(Day[, 6:9], list(Day$Date), mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I got the following warning:

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

and the "Room" column in the new dataset "newDay" results in NAs.

Is it because the "Room" column is a factor? How should I deal this issue?

Comment: Do you mean you want to aggregate by day and room number?

Comment: by Date and Room number

Comment: If the "Room" column is a factor, shouldn't it be one of your grouping variables rather than one of the result variables?

Comment: do you want this: `aggregate(as.matrix(Day[, 7:9]) ~ Date+Room), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE, data=Day)`

Comment: @AnandaMahto what I need is a new dataframe with Date, Room, Temperature, Light, RH, aggregated by Date

Comment: @jogo, just be careful with the formula method and `NA` values in base R's `aggregate`. It sometimes does things you don't expect.

Comment: @Luisa, for "Room", what do you want if there are multiple rooms for a given date?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, thank you for mention it. it's about `na.action=`, isn't it?

Comment: @AnandaMahto There are two rooms 1 and 2

Comment: @jogo, yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16844613/1270695. Luisa, that doesn't answer the question I asked. What *aggregated value* would you expect if you have two rooms, 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need TimeDay I'll just remove it because the mean function can't be applied. And I'll do it with dplyr's summarise_each and group_by instead of aggregate. In your example you used mean, so I used it too.

```
    Day$TimeDay <- NULL
    library(dplyr)
    newDay <- summarise_each(group_by(Day, Date), funs(mean)) %>%
              select(-Day, -Month, -Year, -Room)
```

Edit:
Added pipe, thanks @r2evans. Removed Room, as it's not necessary.

Comment: Since you introduced dplyr, would the column removal be even easier with `... %>% select(-Day, -Month, -Year)`?

Comment: Thank you @mmstan! Maybe, I didn´t explain clearly what I want to do. I would like to get a dataframe aggregated by Date. As you can see from the dataset there are many observations in the date 02/09/2013, and I want to make the mean of the temperature for that date, in order to get only one observation/row per day..

Comment: I do get your desired output with this when I recreate your dataset, one date per row and means of temperature. Is usage of aggregate function mandatory?

Comment: @mmstan Have you tried this? newDay <- summarise_each(group_by(Day, Date), funs(mean)) %>%
        select(-Day, -Month, -Year)  Why the "Room" column result is NA ?

Comment: @Luisa function mean() is applied to column "Room", if it produces NA there might be NAs in your "Room" column. But even if there were no NAs, with the command you've written you'll get mean of Room numbers, which is not very useful information. You'll probably want to either include Room in "group_by(Day, Date, Room)" to have rows aggregated by Date and Room, or to remove it from the resulting data frame with this part "select(-Day, -Month, -Year, -Room)" if the Room is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now!