# Aggregate with na.action=na.pass gives unexpected answer

Tags: r, aggregate, na

I use the following data.frame as an example:

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,NA), y=c(2,3))
```

I'd like to sum up the values of y by the variable x. Since there is no common value of x, I would expect aggregation to just give me the original data.frame back, where NA is treated as a group. But aggregation gives me the following results.

```
>aggregate(y ~ x, data=d, FUN=sum)
  x y
1 1 2
```

I've read the documentation about changing the default actions of na.action, but it doesn't seem to give me anything meaningful.

```
>aggregate(y ~ x, data=d, FUN=sum, na.action=na.pass)
  x y
1 1 2
```

What is going on? I don't seem to understand what na.pass is doing in this case. Is there an option to accomplish what I want in R? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're saying that you are considering an `NA` value as a grouping variable? Do you want the `NA` or not? (It's not clear because you're also using `na.rm = TRUE` as part of your testing....

Comment: Yes, I want NA as a group.

Comment: The documentation says "Rows with missing values in any of the by variables will be omitted from the result." If you don't want this, you need to recode your `by` variable or use a different function for aggregation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`aggregate` makes use of `tapply`, which in turn makes use of `factor` on its grouping variable.

But, look at what happens with `NA` values in `factor`:

```
factor(c(1, 2, NA))
# [1] 1    2    <NA>
# Levels: 1 2
```

Note the `levels`. You can make use of `addNA` to keep the `NA`:

```
addNA(factor(c(1, 2, NA)))
# [1] 1    2    <NA>
# Levels: 1 2 <NA>
```

Thus, you would probably need to do something like:

```
aggregate(y ~ addNA(x), d, sum)
#   addNA(x) y
# 1        1 2
# 2     <NA> 3
```

Or something like:

```
d$x <- addNA(factor(d$x))
str(d)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "1",NA: 1 2
#  $ y: num  2 3
aggregate(y ~ x, d, sum)
#      x y
# 1    1 2
# 2 <NA> 3
```

---

(Alternatively, make the upgrade to something like "data.table", which will not just be faster than `aggregate`, but which will also give you more consistent behavior with `NA` values. No need to pay heed to whether you're [using the formula method of `aggregate` or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844613/na-values-and-r-aggregate-function).)

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(d)[, sum(y), by = x]
#     x V1
# 1:  1  2
# 2: NA  3
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I am curious about the functionality of na.pass. The documentation says that it "returns the object unchanged." So why are the NA's seemingly being removed?

Comment: @Sanias, that is in reference to the columns being aggregated, not the "by" columns.