# Creating dataframe using aggregate in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am trying to create a dataframe from an existing dataframe, retaining only specific columns, for a specified column value (a species in my data). Essentially I intend on creating separate dataframes for each species in my dataset, detailing the stations they were landed at, and retaining the raising agent for the hauls (RF.haul).

My reprex is

```
QSC <- with(Dataframe[Dataframe$Species=="QSC", ], aggregate(number=RF.haul), by(Station=Station), FUN = sum, na.rm= TRUE)
```

I get various errors, mostly "object not found" RE the column headings in the code, and I'm sure this is a relatively easy thing to do in R - I just can't get my head around it (I'm new to R!)

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry but that's not a reprex. A reproducible example should be reproducible. But without Dataframe I can't run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `RF.haul` is a numeric column, consider formula style in `aggregate` using `data` argument and `cbind` to rename numeric column. Note: `na.action` argument added to handle missings with aggregate formula style. *See* @Rorschach's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844940/1422451).

```
QSC <- aggregate(cbind(number = RF.haul) ~ Station, 
                 data = Dataframe[Dataframe$Species=="QSC", ], 
                 FUN=function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
                 na.action = na.pass)
```

And to build a list of data frames by *Species*, add this to the grouping terms with *Station* and then run `split` for named list of data frames. Using a single list is arguably a better choice than many, separate data frames in global environment. *See* @GregorThomas' [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/1422451).

```
agg_df <- aggregate(cbind(number = RF.haul) ~ Species + Station, 
                    data = Dataframe, 
                    FUN=function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE), 
                    na.action = na.pass)

species_agg_dfs <- split(agg_df, agg_df$Species)

species_agg_dfs$QS
...
```