# Why do I get "unused argument (na.action = NULL)" error in aggregate?

Tags: r, aggregate, na

I aggregate data containing `NA`s and therefore I include `na.action = NULL` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844613/aggregate-methods-treat-missing-values-na-differently). Here is the code that works:

```
# Toy data.
df <- data.frame(x= 1:10, group= rep(1:2, 5), other_var= rnorm(10))
# Aggragate with formula.
aggregate(formula= x ~ group, data= df, na.action= NULL, FUN= function(i) sum(i))
```

In my situation I can not provide variable names as formula because they can change. Thus, I provide them with a string vecor in `x` and `by` argument like that:

```
var_names <- c("x", "group")
aggregate(x= df[ , var_names[1]],  by= list(df[ , var_names[2]]), na.action= NULL, FUN= function(i) sum(i))
```

This results in an error. Interestingly, leaving out `na.action= NULL`, e.g. `aggregate(x= df[ , var_names[1]],  by= list(df[ , var_names[2]]), FUN= function(i) sum(i))`, does not end with an error but returns the expected output. How can I avoid that rows containing `NA`s disappear while providing column names as a vetor? I do need to include `na.action= NULL` because my real data contains `NA`s.

Comment: Study the documentation. Only `aggregate.formula` has an `na.action` argument.

Comment: I find your example confusing. The linked post describes a different situation, namely if you have `.` on the LHS of the formula. Since you don't have that, I don't understand why you fiddle with the `na.action` argument at all.

Comment: @Roland You are right, my example data is not good. It does not even contain NAs. I just made data to reproduce the error. Of course my real data looks different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the column names in `aggregate.formula`.
`na.pass` should solve your `na.action` requirements.

```
setNames( 
   aggregate( cbind(df[,1], df[,3]) ~ df[,2], df, sum, na.rm=T, 
   na.action=na.pass ), colnames(df[,c(2,1,3)]) )
  group  x  other_var
1     1 25 -0.7313815
2     2 30  0.3231317
```

##### Data

(I added `NA`s)

```
df <- structure(list(x = 1:10, group = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), other_var = c(-1.79458090358371, 0.295106071151792, 
NA, -0.589487588239041, 0.325944874015228, NA, 0.737254570399201, 
0.47849317537615, NA, 0.139020009150021)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is: assigning `na.action=NULL` means to ignore them and pass any values including their `NA`s to the function, untouched. This is what will happen by default in the non-formula version.

So I suggest you just *omit* `na.action`.

Using  `mtcars`:

```r
mt <- mtcars
mt$mpg[3] <- NA
var_names <- c("mpg", "cyl")
```

First, the formula variant:

```r
aggregate(
  as.formula(paste(var_names[1], "~", var_names[2])), data= mt,
  na.action= NULL,
  FUN= function(i) sum(i))
#   cyl   mpg
# 1   4    NA
# 2   6 138.2
# 3   8 211.4
```

Second, the non-formula failure:

```r
aggregate(
  x= mt[ , var_names[1]],  by= list(mt[ , var_names[2]]),
  na.action= NULL,
  FUN= function(i) sum(i))
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (na.action = NULL)
```

Fixing it:

```r
aggregate(
  x= mt[ , var_names[1]],  by= list(mt[ , var_names[2]]),
  # na.action= NULL,
  FUN= function(i) sum(i))
#   Group.1     x
# 1       4    NA
# 2       6 138.2
# 3       8 211.4
```

Optionally if you want a sum for that first group, then handle it in the function itself:

```r
aggregate(
  x= mt[ , var_names[1]],  by= list(mt[ , var_names[2]]),
  FUN= function(i) sum(i, na.rm=TRUE))
#   Group.1     x
# 1       4 270.5
# 2       6 138.2
# 3       8 211.4
```

Comment: Okay, so is there a reason you choose to *not* use the formula version (as demonstrated in my answer)? It is the only `aggregate` method that uses the `na.action=` which you think you must use.

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve your problem.

```
aggregate(x = df[which(!is.na(df[var_names[1]])), var_names[1]],
      by = list(df[which(!is.na(df[var_names[1]])), var_names[2]]),
      FUN = function(i) sum(i))
```