# Error for NA using group_by or aggregate function [aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : no rows to aggregate]

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I've recently picked up R programming and have been looking through some group_by/aggregate questions posted here to help me learn better. A question came to my mind earlier today on how group_by/aggregate can incorporate ***NA*** data rather than 0.

Given the table and code below (credits to max_lim for allowing me to use his data set), what happens if the field of NA exist (which does happen quite often)?

```
Farms = c(rep("Farm 1", 6), rep("Farm 2", 6), rep("Farm 3", 6))
Year = rep(c(2020,2020,2019,2019,2018,2018),3)
Cow = c(22,NA,16,12,8,NA,31,NA,3,20,39,34,27,50,NA,NA,NA,NA)
Duck = c(12,12,6,NA,NA,NA,28,13,31,50,33,20,NA,9,19,2,NA,7)
Chicken = c(100,120,80,50,NA,10,27,31,NA,43,NA,28,37,NA,NA,NA,5,43)
Sheep = c(30,20,10,NA,16,13,10,20,20,17,48,12,30,NA,20,NA,27,49)
Horse = c(25,20,16,11,NA,12,14,NA,43,42,10,12,42,NA,16,7,NA,42)
Data = data.frame(Farms, Year, Cow, Duck, Chicken, Sheep, Horse)
```

| Farm | Year | Cow | Duck | Chicken | Sheep | Horse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Farm 1 | 2020 | 22 | 12 | 100 | 30 | 25 |
| Farm 1 | 2020 | NA | 12 | 120 | 20 | 20 |
| Farm 1 | 2019 | 16 | 6 | 80 | 10 | 16 |
| Farm 1 | 2019 | 12 | NA | 50 | NA | 11 |
| Farm 1 | 2018 | 8 | NA | NA | 16 | NA |
| Farm 1 | 2018 | NA | NA | 10 | 13 | 12 |
| Farm 2 | 2020 | 31 | 28 | 27 | 10 | 14 |
| Farm 2 | 2020 | NA | 13 | 31 | 20 | NA |
| Farm 2 | 2019 | 3 | 31 | NA | 20 | 43 |
| Farm 2 | 2019 | 20 | 50 | 43 | 17 | 42 |
| Farm 2 | 2018 | 39 | 33 | NA | 48 | 10 |
| Farm 2 | 2018 | 34 | 20 | 28 | 12 | 12 |
| Farm 3 | 2020 | 27 | NA | 37 | 30 | 42 |
| Farm 3 | 2020 | 50 | 9 | NA | NA | NA |
| Farm 3 | 2019 | NA | 19 | NA | 20 | 16 |
| Farm 3 | 2019 | NA | 2 | NA | NA | 7 |
| Farm 3 | 2018 | NA | NA | 5 | 27 | NA |
| Farm 3 | 2018 | NA | 7 | 43 | 49 | 42 |

If I were to use aggregate(.~Farms + Year, Data, mean) here, I would get Error in ***aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : no rows to aggregate*** which I assume is because the ***mean*** function isn't able to account for **NA**.

Does anyone know how we can modify the aggregate/group_by function to account for the NA by calculating the average using only years without NA data? i.e.
2020: 10, 2019: NA, 2018:20, 2017:NA, 2016:15 -> the average (after discounting NA years 2019 and 2017) will be (10 + 20 + 15) / (3) = 15.

The ideal output will be as follow:

| Farm | Year | Cow | Duck | Chicken | Sheep | Horse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Farm 1 | 2020 | 22 (avg = 22/1 as one entry is NA) | 12 | 110 | 25 | 22.5 |
| Farm 1 | 2019 | 14 | 6 | 65 | 10 | 13.5 |
| Farm 1 | 2018 | 8 | N.A. (as it's all NA) | 10 | 14.5 | 12 |
| Farm 2 | 2020 | 31 | 20.5 | 29 | 15 | 14 |
| Farm 2 | 2019 | 11.5 | 40.5 | 43 | 18.5 | 42.5 |
| Farm 2 | 2018 | 36.5 | 26.5 | 28 | 30 | 11 |
| Farm 3 | 2020 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Farm 3 | 2019 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Farm 3 | 2018 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844835) answer your question?

Comment: Hello, tried the (na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL) in aggregate function previously and it did not account in the NA. It calculated the average using all the years and not the years without NA data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to create the wanted data.frame. I think your solution has one error in row 2 (Sheep), where mean(NA, 10) is equal to 5 and not 10.

```
library(dplyr)
```

**Using aggregate**

```
 Data %>% 
  aggregate(.~Year+Farms,., FUN=mean, na.rm=T, na.action=NULL) %>% 
  arrange(Farms, desc(Year)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%  
  mutate_at(names(.), ~replace(., is.nan(.), NA))
```

**Using summarize**

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(Year, Farms) %>% 
  summarize(MeanCow = mean(Cow, na.rm=T),
            MeanDuck =  mean(Duck, na.rm=T),
            MeanChicken = mean(Chicken, na.rm=T),
            MeanSheep = mean(Sheep, na.rm=T),
            MeanHorse = mean(Horse, na.rm=T)) %>% 
  arrange(Farms, desc(Year)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate_at(names(.), ~replace(., is.nan(.), NA))
```

**Solution for both**

```
      Year  Farms  Cow Duck Chicken Sheep Horse
1 2020 Farm 1 22.0 12.0     110  25.0  22.5
2 2019 Farm 1 14.0  6.0      65  10.0  13.5
3 2018 Farm 1  8.0   NA      10  14.5  12.0
4 2020 Farm 2 31.0 20.5      29  15.0  14.0
5 2019 Farm 2 11.5 40.5      43  18.5  42.5
6 2018 Farm 2 36.5 26.5      28  30.0  11.0
7 2020 Farm 3 38.5  9.0      37  30.0  42.0
8 2019 Farm 3   NA 10.5      NA  20.0  11.5
9 2018 Farm 3   NA  7.0      24  38.0  42.0
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply! In row 2 (Sheep) there's actually no error because for 2019, the mean(NA, 10) is (in this case) equal to 10 because we have to discount away the NA (and it's year) which means the mean in this case will be 10/1 rather than 10/2 (because one of the year is NA)

Comment: Do you want to remove the NA from the table?

Comment: Ideally if both of the value for the year is NA, it should be printed as N.A.

Comment: @Luther_Proton: see my edit to change all NaN to NA in the data.frame. I'm not sure if you understood me right regarding the sheep entry for row 2. In your example of the solution there is a 5, however it should be 10 as you already stated yourself.

Comment: @JKupzig, Thank you for that! Indeed I made a mistake with the sheep entry for row 2. Made the edits. Your code works well and it has helped greatly :) Thank you so much for your help!